# Mercurial Commit Charts / Graphs

Tags: mercurial, graph, charts

Is there anything that can produce pretty charts / graphs for Mercurial commit history in a repository? I'm thinking something like what GitHub makes (only for Mercurial):
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just do `hg serve` and then connect to http://localhost:8000 and a graph very similar to that will be on the 'chart' tab of that web page.  As Wim points out you get the same behavior from running hgweb in a webserver, but you can do it with just Mercurial too.

Answer (score 8):

I like the Mercurial [Activity extension](http://labs.freehackers.org/projects/hgactivity), which creates a graph over time, with commits per user and displays tags as milestones:
[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I had some issues setting this up on my Windows system though, so I wrote a [step-by-step guide](http://alinium.posterous.com/how-to-chart-your-mercurial-commit-activity-w) for anyone else interested.

Comment: How is this a network graph?

Comment: @Alinium Your link is dead. Do you have an updated link?

Comment: @HansHarhoff updated link: http://blog.muhammada.li/how-to-chart-your-mercurial-commit-activity-w

Answer (score 2):

If you [publish your repository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) on a webserver with hgweb/hgwebdir, then you can [see the history](http://selenic.com/repo/hg-stable/graph/75d0c38a0bca) in your webbrowser.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseHg's repository explorer has visual commit graphs (albeit in a vertical format, as opposed to a horizontal one) - not sure how useful those would be to you, if you're trying to export them to images or the like or just use them yourself.

Comment: Yea, I saw that. Reminded me of GitExtensions. The motivation behind my wanting to make these charts isn't really even related to productivity, I just think they look cool.