# Jenkins scm contribution charts plugin?

Tags: jenkins, mercurial

Is there a Jenkins plugin showing charts comparable to Github's Contribution chart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly like github's contribution chart, but there's some similar things, but they are made for your source code browser / web interface rather than Jenkins:

- the 'activity extension' for mercurial: http://labs.freehackers.org/projects/hgactivity/wiki; 
  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689605/mercurial-commit-charts-graphs) was a useful question after all - it pointed me there.
- the 'contribution chart' https://mattyboy.net/general/mercurial-contribution-charts/
- and a small separate programme which can generate it, too: pepper: http://jgehring.github.io/pepper/documentation/
- ... (something which I surely missed)

Comment: I couldn't find a plugin either. But Pepper seems to be a good source for charts. Thanks !